Почему не корректно работает RewriteRule в htaccess
Почему в данном коде всегда отрабатывает RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
Например, из url www.сайт.ru/категории/товары?catalog=123 получается www.сайт.ru/index.php/товары
Надо чтобы получился url без гет параметра catalog
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?catalog=[^&]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301]

